# imageWithContentsOfFile resizes the image

Tags: ios

I'm having problems with imageWithContentsOfFile. I have an image with size 640 × 1136 pixels which is supposed to be an background image of the app start screen. The file can be updated and will then be downloaded automatically. My idea was to have one file and resize and crop it for smaller screens.

Bu when i load the image, the size is only 320 wide. I have placed it in the simulator documents folder with Finder, so I can see that the file image is correct. Have also tried naming the file with @2x without success.

This is my code

```
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

CGSize loadedImgSize = bgImage.size;
```

By the way, are compiling for iOS 5.0 to support not updated devices...

Comment: I don't see why this would be happening; are you certain you are loading the correct image?

Comment: You can scale image with required size if you have this problem. It is a good solution for you i think.

Comment: I quite sure its the right image. If I move/rename it the img will not load (of course :-) )

Comment: I want to have hi def on the retina screen, so scaling up is not an option. My idea was to scale down for non retina, and crop top for 4S (3,5" with retina)

Comment: Well. Since you already provide the image by a webservice, why not host all image sizes needed on the webservice and just donwload the needed image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit, CoreGraphics, Quartz, etc. all treat sizes in points, not in pixels. One point = 1 pixel on a non-retina device, one point = 2 pixels on a retina device (same applies to images with and without the `@2x` suffix). It's normal that the with of the image is 320.

Comment: Ok that explains it. Actually it makes it easier for me, then I only crop 44 points of the top on the 3,5" inch screens. Thanks alot.